# Is it possible to program a BlackBerry smartphone using C# and managed code?

Tags: c#, blackberry, smartphone

Is there any way possible to run C# code on a BlackBerry OS smartphone? I've got some Windows Mobile 5.x/6.0 frameworks written in C# that my team needs to "port" to various smartphone platform. We're looking at the following smartphone OS's:

- Windows Phone 7 - VS 2010, Windows Phone Developer Tool CTP, Silverlight, XNA
- iOS - MonoTouch, MonoDevelop IDE
- Android - MonoDroid (when released), MonoDevelop IDE, Mono Tools for Visual Studio
- BlackBerry OS - ???

Research didn't turn up any other programming options for BlackBerry OS but Java/J2ME. I know it's a long shot but was hoping someone here might know of some other options. At this point, I'd even consider a C#-to-Java translator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm curious why the mono project haven't created an development specific for the blackberry OS.  They were working on a version for WebOS until HP messed things up in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your only options for BlackBerry apps are:

1. J2ME/CLDC native app
2. BlackBerry widget using Javascript/HTML

Answer (score 0):

Maybe soon, this is from august 09, so maybe late summer?.

> We’ve been gathering details over the
>   past month or so on this, and **it’s
>   pretty much confirmed: Research In
>   Motion is planning on integrating full
>   Flash and Microsoft Silverlight
>   support into their BlackBerry web
>   browser. Read that again boys and
>   girls** — full Flash support, not Flash
>   lite. You know when the word
>   “planning” is used in the same
>   sentence as RIM, however, that it
>   probably means it’s a while away. And
>   it is. **We’ve been told this won’t
>   happen until next summer or right
>   before it as RIM needs their devices
>   to be more beefed up** as well as have
>   access to higher data speeds for this
>   to work effectively (HSPA and LTE).
>   RIM has already achieved over 10Mbps
>   downloads on next generation
>   BlackBerrys in the test labs with test
>   LTE equipment so it’s looking good,
>   folks.

Comment: ohh forgot the link http://www.boygeniusreport.com/2009/08/19/rim-planning-on-including-full-flash-and-silverlight-support-in-browser/